# How to select distinct/union from two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
Table 1

    id  date   
    1   01-JAN-2011  
    2   01-JAN-2011    
    3   01-JAN-2011

Table 2

    id   index
    1       01
    1       05
    1       06
    2       01
    2       02
    3       01
    3       07
```

I'm trying to list all id-numbers once, where is no index number 06 or 07 in any entry for that id. So in this case, for example, I should get only id 2 as a result. Table 1 I need to use for date search.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM table2 t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM table2
                    WHERE t.id = id
                      AND index IN ('06', '07'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to post actual table definitions/insert statements, so that people can write and test their solutions against them. Here's my attempt, using sample tables below:

```
select ID from T2
except
select ID from T2 where Indx in ('06','07')
```

This has been tested in SQL Server 2008.

Sample tables:

```
create table T2 (
    ID int not null,
    Indx char(2) not null
)
go
insert into T2(ID,Indx)
select 1,'01' union all
select 1,'05' union all
select 1,'06' union all
select 2,'01' union all
select 2,'02' union all
select 3,'01' union all
select 3,'07'
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Nominally, Table 1 is immaterial given the conditions you specify:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id
  FROM Table2 AS t2
 WHERE t2.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2a.id
                       FROM Tble2 AS t2a
                      WHERE t2a.index IN('06', '07')
                    );
```

However, if you only want entries that also match an id in Table 1, then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
  FROM Table1 AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id
          FROM Table2 AS t2
         WHERE t2.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2a.id
                               FROM Tble2 AS t2a
                              WHERE t2a.index IN('06', '07')
                            )
       ) AS t3
    ON t1.id = t3.id;
```

Note that I encoded the index as a character string '06', '07' because the leading zero is immaterial if the index is in fact a numeric column.  If your Table.Index column is actually some numeric type, drop the quotes and the leading zeroes; it might even give (slightly) better performance for you.